# Is arbitrage betting haram?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

Sometimes betting companies (who are of course bad) offer special promotions which gives you the chance to do *arbitrage* betting, meaning that it is possible to bet such that you win the same amount of money *regardless* of the outcome, if you bet the proper amount on different events. Is placing such a bet halal or haram? The money that you get does not depend on the outcome, moreover, you only take it from a betting company that ruins people.

Also, if I *know* the outcome of an event for sure, is it allowed to bet on it at a betting company?

Comment: So if I'm correct you'll win money if you're bet on the winning team and don't lose money when betting on the losing team or betting on the wrong prediction? This still makes it haram. Because Allah prohibited gambling, you just shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Anon No, you win the same amount of money regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Why would you even participate then?

Comment: To make money...

Comment: How do you make money if you only win your own money back (based on your description in your question I don't see the point why one should bother participating).

Comment: I think that you misunderstood something. I never wrote that you only win your own money back. Imagine it like a coin toss. If I bet 1, company A gives me 2 winnings for heads (and I lose my bet if it's tails). But company B might give me 2 for tails. So if I bet 1 at each company, at one of them I lose 1, but at the other I win 2, so irrespective of the outcome, I make 1.

Comment: Well you have absolute certainty that you'll win some kind of money in that way. But still I'd consider it haram using money and betting money even though you're certain about the outcome that you'll win according to  Ayat 219, Surah Al-Baqarah. Every variation of gambling is haram, but research the definition of gambling.

Answer (score -1):

This is a trap and is dangerous because can lead to Haram.

[image]

> Verily those who fear God, think of Him when assailed by the instigations of Satan, and lo! they begin to understand,  [(201)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/7/201/)

This verse says Satan turns around the believer and seeks for a way to enter his mind and soul. so in such cases the believer should be aware and and wise and protect himself.

Comment: I did not down-vote, and I can read your reason very well. Such temptations (which I call bribery to test the week to try haram )  are very common. But you should be more specific on what is wrong instead of *only* throwing in some citations in Arab language when only an estimated half  of the Muslim community can read it. Please explain better.